# Парсинг Android JSON ответа от сервера

Tags: android, json

Столкнулся с таким интересным (интересно построенным) ответом от сервера в формате JSON (Пример подписки на газету).

```
{
"addressData": [
{
  "id": 2223,
  "name": "Респ Дагестан, г Махачкала",
  "description": "2мик. 434дом",
  "house_number": "",
  "flat_number": "",
  "created_at": "2015-08-21T13:01:13.000Z",
  "updated_at": "2015-08-21T13:01:13.000Z",
  "user_id": 20,
  "changed_user_id": null,
  "city": "Махачкала"
},
{
  "id": 2224,
  "name": "Респ Дагестан, г Махачкала",
  "description": "2мик. 597дом",
  "house_number": "",
  "flat_number": "",
  "created_at": "2015-08-21T13:05:51.000Z",
  "updated_at": "2015-08-21T13:05:51.000Z",
  "user_id": 20,
  "changed_user_id": null,
  "city": "Махачкала"
},
{
  "id": 2225,
  "name": "Респ Дагестан, г Махачкала",
  "description": "3 микр. дом 648",
  "house_number": "",
  "flat_number": "",
  "created_at": "2015-09-17T17:52:46.000Z",
  "updated_at": "2015-09-17T17:52:46.000Z",
  "user_id": 20,
  "changed_user_id": null,
  "city": "Махачкала"
} ],
 "newspaperData": [
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": ""Ас-Салам" на русском",
  "manufacturer_id": 1,
  "created_at": "2015-06-23T16:21:45.000Z",
  "updated_at": "2015-06-23T16:21:45.000Z"
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": ""Ас-Салам" на аварском",
  "manufacturer_id": 1,
  "created_at": "2015-06-23T16:21:56.000Z",
  "updated_at": "2015-06-23T16:21:56.000Z"
},
{
  "id": 3,
  "name": ""Ас-Салам" на лезгинском",
  "manufacturer_id": 1,
  "created_at": "2015-07-11T12:56:50.000Z",
  "updated_at": "2015-07-11T12:56:50.000Z"
} ],
 "subscriberData": [
{
  "id": 1111,
  "name": "Гаджи",
  "surname": "Гаджиев",
  "email": "",
  "description": "",
  "user_id": 20,
  "changed_user_id": null,
  "real_status": null,
  "created_at": "2015-08-21T13:01:13.000Z",
  "updated_at": "2015-08-21T13:01:13.000Z",
  "main_phone": "",
  "additional_phone": "",
  "delete_on": null,
  "where_added": "user",
  "added_user_id": null
},
{
  "id": 1112,
  "name": "Шамиль",
  "surname": "Ибрагимов",
  "email": "",
  "description": "",
  "user_id": 20,
  "changed_user_id": null,
  "real_status": null,
  "created_at": "2015-08-21T13:05:51.000Z",
  "updated_at": "2015-08-21T13:05:51.000Z",
  "main_phone": "",
  "additional_phone": "",
  "delete_on": null,
  "where_added": "user",
  "added_user_id": null
},
{
  "id": 1113,
  "name": "Арсланали",
  "surname": "Исаев",
  "email": "",
  "description": "",
  "user_id": 20,
  "changed_user_id": null,
  "real_status": null,
  "created_at": "2015-09-17T17:52:46.000Z",
  "updated_at": "2015-09-17T17:52:46.000Z",
  "main_phone": "",
  "additional_phone": "",
  "delete_on": null,
  "where_added": "user",
  "added_user_id": null
} ],
"subscriptionPeriodData": [
{
  "id": 3874,
  "period_start": "01.01.2015",
  "period_finish": "31.12.2015",
  "description": "",
  "created_at": "2015-08-21T13:01:13.000Z",
  "updated_at": "2015-12-04T17:17:06.000Z",
  "subscriber_id": 1111,
  "user_id": 20,
  "address_id": 2223,
  "changed_user_id": null,
  "newspaper_id": 1,
  "price_paid": 0,
  "price": 0
},
{
  "id": 3875,
  "period_start": "01.07.2015",
  "period_finish": "31.12.2015",
  "description": "",
  "created_at": "2015-08-21T13:05:51.000Z",
  "updated_at": "2015-12-04T17:17:06.000Z",
  "subscriber_id": 1112,
  "user_id": 20,
  "address_id": 2224,
  "changed_user_id": null,
  "newspaper_id": 2,
  "price_paid": 0,
  "price": 0
},
{
  "id": 5172,
  "period_start": "01.07.2015",
  "period_finish": "31.12.2015",
  "description": "",
  "created_at": "2015-09-17T17:52:46.000Z",
  "updated_at": "2015-12-04T17:17:09.000Z",
  "subscriber_id": 1113,
  "user_id": 20,
  "address_id": 2225,
  "changed_user_id": null,
  "newspaper_id": 3,
  "price_paid": 0,
  "price": 0
} ]
}
```

Ответ от сервера на подобие связей таблиц между собой по полю ID.
Нужно получить: ИмяПодписчика, НаименованеГазеты, АдресДоставкиГазеты.
Главная "таблица" с которой все связано - это subscriptionPeriodData.
У кого какие варианты как "связать по ID" и вывести результат?

Comment: А что здесь интересного то? Все вроде элементарно...

Answer (score 1):

Используем [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) для сетевых запросов. Создаем модели и указываем ретрофиту парсер gson.

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать.

Comment: Такой вариант ? http://www.cyberforum.ru/android-dev/thread1611983-new-post.html